# Textmate snippet to add file name and path in comment?

Tags: regex, codeigniter, textmate, code-snippets

I'm using an existing snippet in Textmate to reduce the repetition of creating controllers and models. The snippet works great, but I'd love to add a comment to the end of each file. For example:

```
/* End of file filename.php */  
/* Location: ./system/application/controllers/filename.php */
```

The first line is easy:

```
/* End of file ${TM_FILENAME} */
```

The second part is almost as easy with the TM_FILEPATH variable:

```
/* Location: ./${TM_FILEPATH} */
```

The problem is, I don't want the entire file path returned, just anything AFTER 'system' if it exists, or 'application' if not. For instance, using TM_FILEPATH returns this:

```
/* Location: ./path/from/root/system/application/controllers/filename.php */
-or-
/* Location: ./path/from/root/application/controllers/filename.php */
```

...when I want:

```
/* Location: ./system/application/controllers/filename.php */
-or-
/* Location: ./application/controllers/filename.php */
```

I assume it is going to be some regex trickery, but I have no idea how. Any suggestions please?

---

UPDATE: I just found the TextMate variable TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY which contains the info that I want REMOVED from TM_FILEPATH if that makes things any easier.

So, whereas TM_FILEPATH produces this:

```
/path/from/root/system/application/controllers/filename.php
```

TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY produces this:

```
/path/from/root
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Textmate, but could you use the CI constant FCPATH? This is the full server path to the file.

Comment: Thanks, but no. This is for raw text CI PHP files being created in TextMate, so the CI constants are not even in play yet.

However, I just found the TextMate variable TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY which contains the info that I want REMOVED from TM_FILEPATH if that makes things any easier.

So, whereas TM_FILEPATH produces this:

    /path/from/root/system/application/controllers/filename.php

TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY produces this:

    /path/from/root

Answer (score 0):

I use two different snippets for controllers and models (since the syntax is similar, but just a bit different; I.E.: every controller needs an index function, but models don't). I just hard code them as follows...

Controller:

```
/* Location: ./application/controllers/${TM_FILENAME} */
```

Model:

```
/* Location: ./application/models/${TM_FILENAME} */
```

Since I **always** pull the application folder out of the system folder, and put the system folder in a different directory, this works out great. I also added a tabstop on application, just in case I renamed the application directory.

@TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY: I think this only works if you open your files as a project. I use e text editor, which is based on Textmate, so it might be a little bit different.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I generally pull the applications folder out too, but I'd like to have the snippet be smart enough to work in either case.

The TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY is only set if you are working in a project. I knew that, but hadn't really considered the ramifications of say, adding a controller without being 'in' the project.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the solution I came up with. I have no idea if it is the best way, but it seams to work:

```
/* End of file ${TM_FILENAME} */
/* Location: ${TM_FILEPATH/(.*?)(\/system)?(\/application.*)/(?1:).$2$3/} */
```

I'll break it down as much as I understand it ;)

```
${TM_FILEPATH      - The 'source' string TextMate variable
/                  - Indicates next chars are 'pattern'
(.*?)              - Group 1: Zero or more of any character. ? Makes it non-greedy
(\/system)?        - Group 2: /system but it's optional because of the ?
(\/application.*)  - Group 3: /application and any other characters
/                  - Indicates next chars are 'replacement'
(?1:).$2$3         - If Group 1 is found, replace with blank, then a dot, Group 2, Group 3.
/                  - Indicates regex is finished.
}                  - Closes off TextMate variable.
```